# Prove there exists a constant $C$ such that $y_2(x)=Cy_1(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1(x),y_2(x)$ be the solutions of $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ and satisfy that $y_1(x_0)=y_2(x_0)=0$，$y_1(x) \neq 0$ where $p(x),q(x)$ are continuous over $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and $x_0$ be some real number. Prove there exists a constant $C$ such that $y_2(x)=Cy_1(x)$.

Since at $x_0$ we have $y_1(x_0)=y_2(x_0)=0$ Then $W(y_1,y_2) = 0 \Rightarrow y_1 $ and $y_2$ are linearly depedendent $\Rightarrow$ $y_2(x)=Cy_1(x)$. This will work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works.

Since $W(y_1,y_2)(x_0)=0$, it proves that $W(y_1,y_2)$ is identically $0$, and the two solutions are linearly dependent.

That implies that $y_2(x) = Cy_1(x)$ for some constant $C$